# Blazor Server get current page only without parameters

Tags: blazor

I have a blazor server application and I want to get the current page name in order to persist data for that page for other reasons.

I can see that the NavigationManager provides the full uri (so http://site:1234/page) and also the base uri (so http://site:1234) and I can determine the page by removing the base uri from the full uri to get the /page component.

However, if the page has parameters passed to it then the uri becomes http://site:1234/page/param1/param2 and it's then dificult to reliably determine the page name from the full uri.

This is compounded further if you then have a nested page structure, so http://site:1234/category/page/param1/param2.

One approach was to use a variable for the @page directive however this is not exposed outside the component without making it bubble up\down the hierachy so if I wanted to get the current page from the Navigation\appLayout component I would then need to casecade (bring up?) the paremter for each page that this requires.

Another approach would be to switch to a more formal querystring approach (so /page?param1=value&param2=value etc) however this also would mean every page then needs to be changed to then read and interpret that string rather than relying on the default blazor parameter interpretation.

I would be ok with the full path (so /category/page)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Router component exposes RouteData which has a PageType property.

So, if you cascade the RouteData, you can pick it up anywhere you need it.

In your `App` component

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="routeData" IsFixed=true>
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

And in any other Layout/Component you can receive that data

```
[CascadingParameter] public RouteData routeData { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] curPage = NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri).Split("/");
```

Comment: curpage[0] is the page name

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure in my answer. If I'm wrong please forgive me.
In blazor there is an object named NavigationManager.
I don't have a computer at the moment, but you can try with NavigationManager.BaseUri

Comment: Try this one: `CurrUrl = NavigationManager.Uri.ToString().ToLower();
        CurrUrl = CurrUrl.Replace(NavigationManager.BaseUri, "");`

Comment: If you read my initial question, this almost works... However the NavigationManager.Uri also includes any parameter info which will change per execution of the page so not what I need.